# How can I match the angle of projection from a book illustration?

Tags: drafting, solidworks, cad

I have translated the part illustrated below into Solidworks but I haven't been able to match the angle of projection used in the illustration.

[image]

How can I identify that angle used in the image, so that I can reproduce the figure as closely as possible?

The drawing is from an old book by Thomas French.

Comment: Can't you take a given dimension (say 1 9/16), measure what the scaled dimension on the page is and use trigonometry? Also, you are assuming that the original image was draw "correctly".

Comment: Your illustration looks like an *oblique* projection. These were often used to simplify the drawing process, before computer graphics. If that is correct, the view does not correspond to any *orthographic* projection that gives a "realistic" view of the object (even if you ignore perspective). So you won't be able to reproduce "the exact same view" starting from "correct" 3-D geometry with  modern CAD software. You could reproduce it by first distorting the geometry, e.g. by applying a shear transformation to the structure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection

Comment: For anyone who's interested in pursuing this, I uploaded the model in STEP and STL here: https://grabcad.com/library/end-plate-2. Also (@Ricardo), is that one measurement 9/6? It's the only improper fraction in the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple isometric projection
The angle is, by the picture 30.
[image]

Comment: Yes but for it to be isometric you would need  the other directipns to follow suite... But the other direction sideways is horisontal